# Retrieve specific data from REST Json response based on condition

Tags: java, json, rest, data-retrieval

I looked at all related posts but I couldn't find what I am looking for.
Verified the query syntax by using https://codebeautify.org/jsonpath-tester and https://jsonpath.com/. In below code, I get correct response if I print just id. I am looking for title, based on specific userID and id.

Getting "Invalid JSON expression" as o/p. Can anyone pls help here!

```
public void restPost2(){
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    RequestSpecification req = RestAssured.given().log().all();
    String res1 = req.given().when().get().then().extract().asString();
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res1);
    System.out.println("list of Ids : " + js.get("id"));
    System.out.println("specific title : " + js.get("(?(@.userId == '3') && (@.id == '23')).title"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following changes will solve your issue.

- Use JsonPath.read to set json string to be queries
- Syntax of jsonPath queries need to be corrected.

[suggest you to refer jsonPath documentation again.](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Please find a working example

```
json = <data fetched for the api>

        Object x = JsonPath.read(json,"$..id");

        Object y = JsonPath.read(json,"$[?(@.userId == 3 && @.id == 23)]");
```

Comment: Still getting below error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: ? @ line 1, column 30.
                            $.(?(@.userId == '3') && (@.id == '23')).title
                                ^